# CKEditor, how to delete empty paragraphs before and between widgets

Tags: widget, ckeditor

If you have an empty paragraph before a widget, it cannot be deleted, nor can an empty paragraph after, or between widgets be deleted, except by viewing the source.

This is evident on the CKEditor demo page here: http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets

simply clear all the content to start, add a paragraph, add a widget, and try to remove the first paragraph.

Note that in my configuration I am not filling empty paragraphs with a non-breaking space, and I get the same behavior, so that doesn't seem to be related.
[image]

This really does create a problem for a content management system.

Answer (score 6):

This is a known [issue](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12778), but there's no patch yet. This would require some additional rules for delete and backspace, so if the current paragraph is already empty they should remove it instead of focusing widget. This code could land e.g. here: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/3a10930/core/selection.js#L339-L365.